# after deleting some files. space is not freed

Tags: ubuntu, disk-usage, deleted-files

after deleting some files. space is not freed.
by running the command `df -h` the free space is always 0.

```
 /dev/sda3 233G 224G 0 100% /
```

even after rebooting the system

output `df -h;ls -l file_to_be_erased;rm file_to_be_erased;df -h` :

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  680K  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/sda3       233G  216G  5.2G  98% /
tmpfs           7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           2.0G  188K  2.0G   1% /home/fold1
tmpfs            15G  139M   14G   1% /home/fold2
/dev/sda1       487M   59M  399M  13% /boot
tmpfs           1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/0

ls: cannot access 'file_to_be_erased': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'file_to_be_erased': No such file or directory

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  680K  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/sda3       233G  216G  5.2G  98% /
tmpfs           7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           2.0G  188K  2.0G   1% /home/fold1
tmpfs            15G  139M   14G   1% /home/fold2
/dev/sda1       487M   59M  399M  13% /boot
tmpfs           1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/0
```

Comment: We need more information. Paste the output of `df -h;ls -l file_to_be_erased;rm file_to_be_erased;df -h`.

Comment: Instead of using `rm` and `ls -l` on file_to_be_erased, you need to use it on an actual file on the partition mounted at `/`. Replace the lines with the error messages with the output of what I just stated.

Comment: I don't understand why even restarting the server the processes do not let you delete the files.

Comment: Please don't post output from memory. Or re-type it, Paste the real exact same text.

Comment: Can you describe what you mean when you say "the processes do not let you delete the files"? Are you getting a Permission Denied error?

Comment: Help me out - I can't see the line saying `/dev/sda3` has `0` available and `100%` use in your given output. So mayhap your delete actions (whatever they hit) had some effect already?

Comment: From what I know from AIX, at least your / or /var isn't full or you cannot reboot ! In any case, the useful tool there is lsof / to check which files are still on hold by a process (perhaps the process disappears but PID is still there).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not delete any files.  If you look into your ouput, you'll see:
ls: cannot access 'file_to_be_erased': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'file_to_be_erased': No such file or directory

So, substitute 'file_to_be_erased' with real name of files to be deleted.  You might need to delete a lot of files prior to df show you visible improvement.  Try to find the biggest files (using find command) and start with those.

Comment: In fact it's so .! thank you